# Trying to graph a parabola and horizontal lines in pgf plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to graph the following graph and so far I only have code to graph the parabola, could someone help me graph the dashed horizontal and vertical lines.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    yticklabels=\empty,
    xticklabels=\empty,
]

\addplot [
    domain=0:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! Take a look at this post, for example:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493748/use-pgfplots-to-generate-this-picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert function equation, which you like to draw, directly to `\addplot` command, for example:

```
\addplot +[ultra thick, color=purple, domain=0:2] {x^2};
```

or define function in `axis options as is done in MWE (Minimal Working Example) below.

Point on function curve you can define as `(<x>,{f(x){)` or you calculate manually or use in your case select `x=1` where `f(\x) = (\x^2)` is 1 (as is used in MWE below.

MWE should work also with older version of `pgfplots`, but not the oldest as `compat=v1.11`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
declare function = {f(\x)=(\x)^2);},
    axis lines=left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $f(x)$,
    xmin=0,    xmax=2.2,         xtick=\empty,
    ymin=0,    ymax=4.4,         ytick=\empty,
    domain=0:2,
    no marks,
    every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick, color=magenta,},
            ]
\addplot    {f(x)} node[right,text=black] {$x^2$};
\draw[dashed] (0,1) -- (1,1) node[above left] {$b$}
                             node[below right] {$a$}
                   -- (1,0); 
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]