# plot the equation in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the plot of the equation

[image]

I've tried to solve that with the following link:
https://latexdraw.com/plot-a-function-and-data-in-latex

However I don't know how to draw two cases.

Besides I want to add some parts to the figure. Like the X and Y in others in the attached figure. Could you help me with that?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot[] {2-3*exp(-x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question is very similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599764/trying-to-graph-a-parabola-and-horizontal-lines-in-pgf-plot/599765#599765. See. if answer on it can help you (you only have slightly different function). Try to use this answer an construct own picture. BTW, defining of function, which you like to draw, is not really LaTeX problem ;-)

Comment: You haven't said which equation you want to plot. Judging by your second image you want to plot a sawtooth like function, and not an exponential? If that is the case, perhaps easiest to just choose some appropriate coordinates, e.g.  `\addplot coordinates {(0,-1) (5,5) (10,-1)};`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the comment. I've just edited the question.

Comment: @Zarko thanks for the comment. Yes. they are the same. However, the problem for me is that it contains two different functions for different time periods.

Comment: Your second link doesn't work.

Comment: `domain=x1:x2` to set the domain for a function, e.g. `\addplot[domain=0:2] {2-3*exp(-x)};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can use `plot` which is a path operation that allows drawing functions (as the one in your example).

The other solution might be using `addplot` which requires the package `pgfplots`, but I think that *fewer is better*, at least when you begin learning something.

I represented the function on [0, 4] (rescaling the *y*-axis) since otherwise, the numbers become too large for `TikZ`.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=.7cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}

\xdefinecolor{B}{RGB}{17, 97, 204}
\tikzmath{
  real \b, \ys;
  \ys = .2;
  \b = {2 -3*pow(e, 2)};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=\ys, every node/.style={scale=.8}]
  % axes
  \draw[very thin, ->] (-.5, 0) -- (5, 0) node[below=.5ex] {$x$};
  \draw[very thin, ->] (0, -24) -- (0, 20) node[left=.5ex] {$y$};
  % \path (0, 0) node[above left] {$O$};

  % special points
  \draw[gray, thin, dashed] (2, 1ex) node[above, scale=.7] {$2$}
  -- (2, {\b}) node[below right, scale=.7] {$(2, \b)$};
  \draw[gray, thin, dashed] (4, -1ex) node[below, scale=.7] {$4$} -- (4, 18);
  \draw[gray, thin, dashed] (-.3ex, -1) node[left, scale=.7] {$-1$} -- (2.1, -1);

  % curve
  \draw[B, thick, variable=\t, domain=0:2, samples=80]
  plot (\t, {2 -3*pow(e, \t)});
  \draw[B, thick, variable=\t, domain=2:4, samples=80]
  plot (\t, {3*pow(e, \t-2) -4});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great response.